# Using c++ ".lib" files in java

Tags: java, c++, dll, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Is there a way to import a C++ ".lib" into java, using either the androind NDK, or the Java JNI?  I do not have the source code to create a dll. which I am aware would provide a way to import into java, however I have not found a way to convert the ".lib" file to a .dll.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts.

Note: The library is a windows ".lib" compiled in C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a Windows/MSVC .lib file with the Android NDK (even if you could, it'd be x86 and most Android devices are ARM). You will need to compile the library from source.

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking at 2 of the many examples that comes with the Android tools, have a particular look for the 2 samples about the use of some external C/C++ libraries that comes with the Android NDK.

Anyway you can't run X86 assembly code on an ARM and viceversa, so the fact that you can use external C++ does not bypass the limit of the targeted architecture by your libraries, to do this you better have the source code for those C++ libraries.

Comment: Those external C/C++ libraries would still need to be ELF shared objects or static libraries, even if they were the correct architecture.

Comment: why they need to be shared? There are a lot of library that are not linked / shared in the Android ecosystem.